# How do I visualize n-dimensional features?

Tags: matlab, grouping, data-analysis

I have two matrices `A` and `B`. The size of `A` is 200*1000 double (here: 1000 represents 1000 different features). Matrix `A` belongs to group 1, where I use `ones(200,1)` as the label vector.  The size of `B` is also 200*1000 double (here: 1000 also represents 1000 different features).  Matrix `B` belongs to group 2, where I use `-1*ones(200,1)` as the label vector.

My question is how do I visualize matrices `A` and `B` so that I can clearly distinguish them based on the given groups?

Comment: What do you mean by draw? Also, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming each sample in your matrices `A` and `B` is determined by a row in either matrix.  If I understand you correctly, you want to draw a series of 1000-dimensional vectors, which is impossible.  We can't physically visualize anything beyond three dimensions.

As such, what I suggest you do is perform a [dimensionality reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionality_reduction) to reduce your data so that each input is reduced to either 2 or 3 dimensions.  Once you reduce your data, you can plot them normally and assign a different marker to each point, depending on what group they belonged to.

If you want to achieve this in MATLAB, use [Principal Components Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis), specifically the [`pca`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pca.html) function in MATLAB, that calculates the residuals and the reprojected samples if you were to reproject them onto a lower dimensionality.  I'm assuming you have the Statistics Toolbox... if you don't, then sorry this won't work.

Specifically, given your matrices `A` and `B`, you would do this:

```
[coeffA, scoreA] = pca(A);
[coeffB, scoreB] = pca(B);
numDimensions = 2;
scoreAred = scoreA(:,1:numDimensions);
scoreBred = scoreB(:,1:numDimensions);
```

The second output of `pca` gives you reprojected values and so you simply have to determine how many dimensions you want by extracting the first `N` columns, where `N` is the desired number of dimensions you want.

I chose 2 for now, and we can see what it looks like in 3 dimensions after.  Once we have what we need for 2 dimensions, it's just a matter of plotting:

```
plot(scoreAred(:,1), scoreAred(:,2), 'rx', scoreBred(:,1), scoreBred(:,2), 'bo');
```

This will produce a plot where the samples from matrix `A` are with red crosses while the samples from matrix `B` are with blue circles.

Here's a sample run given completely random data:

```
rng(123); %// Set seed for reproducibility
A = rand(200,1000); B = rand(200,1000); %// Generate random data

%// Code as before
[coeffA, scoreA] = pca(A);
[coeffB, scoreB] = pca(B);
numDimensions = 2;
scoreAred = scoreA(:,1:numDimensions);
scoreBred = scoreB(:,1:numDimensions);

%// Plot the data
plot(scoreAred(:,1), scoreAred(:,2), 'rx', scoreBred(:,1), scoreBred(:,2), 'bo');
```

We get this:

[image]

If you want three dimensions, simply change `numDimensions = 3`, then change the plot code to use [`plot3`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot3.html):

```
plot3(scoreAred(:,1), scoreAred(:,2), scoreAred(:,3), 'rx', scoreBred(:,1), scoreBred(:,2), scoreBred(:,3), 'bo');
grid;
```

With those changes, this is what we get:

[image]